# Appcelerator Activity Window opens with black background for Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to implement an Activity Indicator for our App. The code I am running is as follows :

```
var indicatorWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    opacity : 1,
    backgroundColor : 'transparent'
});

var activityIndicator = Ti.UI.createActivityIndicator({
    message: 'Loading...'
});

indicatorWindow.add(activityIndicator);
indicatorWindow.addEventListener('indicatorShow', function(e) {
    indicatorWindow.open();
    activityIndicator.show();
});

indicatorWindow.addEventListener('indicatorHide', function(e) {
    activityIndicator.hide();
    indicatorWindow.close();
});
```

And then I am calling the following events from another page :

```
IndicatorWindow.fireEvent('indicatorShow');
Some task here...
IndicatorWindow.fireEvent('indicatorHide');
```

The Activity windows opens up with a Black background instead of a transparent one (see screenshot below). The same code works on Android, iOS and Web though. Any thoughts?
[image: ActivityIndicatorforWindowsPhone]

Comment: It looks like you've found something that works differently across platforms where it shouldn't need to. Thanks! Could you please check if this is a known issue at Appcelerator's [JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/)? If it's not, then create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.